# Documentation or tutorials for Hibernatemock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, hibernate, open-source, persistence

Recently I cam to see Hibernatemock api on link
http://code.google.com/p/hibernatemock/

I couldn't get more documentation for it to understand if i can use it in my project or not.
Some of benefits it has is that i it mocks objects dependencies needed for testing DAO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an article with some code [here](http://www.infoq.com/br/articles/hibernate-mock). Use [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://www.infoq.com/br/articles/hibernate-mock) if you don't read Portuguese. For the code, you can space-separate the identifiers and pass that through Google Translate, e.g. [listarPessoasQueAlugaramCarroNoPeriodo](http://translate.google.com/#auto|en|listar%20Pessoas%20Que%20Alugaram%20Carro%20No%20Periodo). There's also some code on the [project page](http://code.google.com/p/hibernatemock/).

You can also browse through the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/hibernatemock/source/browse/trunk/#trunk%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fhibernatemock) to discover the available functions.

Comment: translation is not correct especially for variable name, method name etc translation is not possible. Where can i get source code for same or some other documentation. i couldn't get same on google.

Comment: @Maddy Updated my answer. Hopefully that helps. There's very little available, sorry.